# How to use a string to generate an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, list, dictionary

I have a long string with this format:

```
A from $37
B from $46
D from $70
P from $61
S from $40
```

This is the expected result:

```
 [{A:$37},{B:$46},{D:$70},{P:$61},{S:$40}]
```

How can I create this output from my string?

Comment: You have a task, not a question. SO is not a free coding service.  I have downvoted this question because there was no evidence of research or an attempt to code your own solution.  Too Broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split them by `\n` and then split by `from`

```js
var f = `A from $37
B from $46
D from $70
P from $61
S from $40`;
var items = new Array();
f.split('\n').forEach((i) => {
   var j = i.split(' from ');
   var json = '{"'+j[0]+'":"'+j[1]+'"}';
   items.push(JSON.parse(json));
});
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var strings = ['A from $37','B from $46','D from $70','P from $61','S from $40'];

var outputArr = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < strings.length;i++){
  var items = strings[i].split(" from ");
  outputArr.push({Key:items[0], Value:items[1]});  
}

console.log(outputArr);
```

You wouldn't be able to create dynamic key in JavaScript object,

You you can add it as a key value object in an array

here is [demo](https://jsbin.com/yunihop/edit?html,js,console) of the snippet

Comment: Thanks man but here you use `var strings = ['A from $37','B from $46','D from $70','P from $61','S from $40'];` is not array which you used but it's a string looking like "A from $37     B from $46        D from $70     P from $61 
   S from $40";

Comment: you need to make array of the string..

Comment: how will it because that string have many space if you have solution please edit your ans

Comment: in es6 you can have dynamic keys as shown in my solution

Comment: @charlietfl great .. thanks +1 frm me

Comment: even in es5 easy to create empty object and use `[]` notation to add property/value to get expected results

Comment: @charlietfl we can create JSON string in es5. but how about JavaScript object?

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex match and es6 dynamic object keys

```js
const str = `
A from $37
B from $46
D from $70
P from $61
S from $40`;

const objectMapper = (s) => {
  const arr = s.match(/(^[a-z]+\b)|(\$.+)/gi);
  return {[arr[0]]: arr[1]};
};
const res = str.trim().split('\n').map(objectMapper)


console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```